# Bash ~ Modify what is to be printed with for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, printf

Ok so I have this line in my bash script as follows:

```
basic_list=$(awk '{printf "%s/%s/%s/%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}' <<< "${STANDARD_LIST}")
```

This as shown will print the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th word on each line of STANDARD_LIST to the variable basic_list (again split using lines)

Now my problem is I also have these commands:

```
basic_list2=$(awk '{printf "%s/%s/%s\n", $1, $2, $3}' <<< "${STANDARD_LIST}")
basic_list3=$(awk '{printf "%s/%s\n", $1, $2}' <<< "${STANDARD_LIST}")
basic_list4=$(awk '{printf "%s\n", $1}' <<< "${STANDARD_LIST}")
```

Is there any way to use a for loop to condense all of these lines into one in bash? (i.e. modify the string for printf to elongate with each iteration of the for loop)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set `bash` variables, don't use `awk`. Work directly in `bash`, with something like

```
declare -a tmp tmp2 tmp3 tmp4
while read -a f; do
    printf -v str '%s/%s/%s/%s' "${f[@]:0:4}"
    tmp+=$str
    tmp2+=${str%/*}
    tmp3+=${str%/*/*}
    tmp4+=${str%/*/*/*}
done <<< "$STANDARD_LIST"
basic_list=$(printf '%s\n' "${tmp[@]}")
basic_list2=$(printf '%s\n' "${tmp2[@]}")
basic_list3=$(printf '%s\n' "${tmp3[@]}")
basic_list4=$(printf '%s\n' "${tmp4[@]}")
```

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realize I could do that, that's perfect thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you wanted to achieve, but once you have a bash array, you can slice it, for example

```
$ source=( a b c d e f )
$ echo "${source[@]}"
a b c d e f

$ echo "${source[@]:0:4}"
a b c d

$ echo "${source[@]:0:3}"
a b c

$ echo "${source[@]:0:2}"
a b

$ echo "${source[@]:0:1}"
a
```

you have defined four variables, perhaps you don't need them at all.

Comment: That could work but sadly $STANDARD_LIST is not formatted that way, thank you for the help